# Joint distributions for uncorrelated varibles

Tags: distributions, self-study, expected-value, joint-distribution

Can someone think of joint distribution of random variables X, Y such that the following three
conditions are satisfied:

$E[X] = 1$,
$E[Y] = 1$,  and
$E[XY] = 0$?

A friend of mine asked me this, which seems simple, but I'm not a stat whiz, so This makes my head spin. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 7):

$(X,Y)$ take on value $(0,2)$ and $(2,0)$ with equal probability $\frac{1}{2}$. Then,
$$E[X] = 0\times\frac{1}{2} + 2\times\frac{1}{2} = 1,$$
and similarly $E[Y]=1$, while
$$E[XY] = 2\times 0\times\frac{1}{2} + 0\times 2\times\frac{1}{2} = 0.$$

Added note: The $X$ and $Y$ in this example are *not* uncorrelated random variables
(cf. the title of the question) but *perfectly (negatively) correlated* random variables
since $X$ and $Y$ have unit variance and $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) = E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]= -1$ giving $\rho_{X,Y}= \frac{\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{var}(X\operatorname{var}(Y)}}= -1$; or more simply from the observation that $Y = 2-X$.
Indeed, it is not possible to have *uncorrelated* random variables with the properties
$$E[X] = E[Y] = 1, \quad E[XY]=0$$ since $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)$ (and therefore
$\rho_{X,Y}$) is necessarily negative.

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation is more than I asked for and I am embarrassed to learn that the solution is so simple on the hindsight...

Comment: @user1330974 You are welcome.  Many of us occasionally don't see things that are staring us in the face and later slap ourselves and go "Duh!"